# Where does the standard tokenlist in Uniswap gets created?

Tags: uniswap

I want to add some standard tokens to Uniswap Interface (https://github.com/Uniswap/interface).

[image: uniswap standard token list]
Where in the code do I need to add the addresses of these tokens.
I noticed that Rinkeby has as standard ETH, DAI, MKR, UNI and WETH but Goerli only has ETH, UNI and WETH.
I have tried to add them in /src/constants/tokens.ts but they dont show up in the standard list.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tokens in @uniswap/build/uniswap-default.tokenlist.json These will show up inthe default list.